# Is there a function that is integrable and continuous on $[a,b]$ but that it is not uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Any hints or exercises that I could use. I do not know how to start this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: A continuous function on a compact set is always uniformly continuous. An assumption about integrability is superfluous here.

Comment: Dang that was fast. Teach me your ways.