# Suppose a function $f(x)$ defined on $(a,b)$ is integrable and continuous on $(a,b)$, does this imply that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have asked a somewhat similar question. Now I am asking a variation of it. The previous question is here:[Is there a function that is integrable and continuous on $[a,b]$ but that it is not uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608738/is-there-a-function-that-is-integrable-and-continuous-on-a-b-but-that-it-is).

$\mathbf{The\;previous\;question}$

The question was not clear enough. I will reword it again.
Suppose that I have a function $f(x):[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x)$ be continuous and Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Is $f(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$? The answer is yes as answered in the question link

$\mathbf{The\;present\;question}$

Now, suppose that I have a function $f(x):[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x)$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and continuous on $(a,b)$. Is $f(x)$ uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$?

I think that the answer is no. I have tried using $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$. However, I realized that I am dealing with Riemann integrals and thus I need the interval to be closed. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, when $ x \in (0,1)$. The function $f$ is continuous in $(0,1)$ and Riemann Integrable in $[0,1]$, improper integration in $[0,1]$ at $0$.

$f$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$, because of infinite discontinuity at $0$. Check using the Cauchy sequence $\{\frac{1}{n^2}\}$.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand what you are implying with the statement "improper integration in $[0,1]$ at $0$." Could you elaborate?

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow o} \int_{\epsilon}^1 f(x) dx$. The function has infinite discontinuity at $0$, not Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$ but we can find out the value of the integration in $[0,1]$, so improper.

Comment: But then, isn't that an extra condition? Or does the definition for the Riemann integral also encompass improper integrals?

Comment: It is an extension or generalization of concepts of Riemann Integration.

Comment: Where can I find this information?

Comment: I do know what improper integrals and Riemann integrals are, I am not familiar with them being related.

Comment: Also, a clarification. When you say Riemann integrals, do you mean Riemann-Stieltjes or Riemann?

Comment: I have thought about it some more, and came to the conclusion that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ does not work since it is not bounded on $(0,1)$. From what I recall, $f(x)$ has to be bounded to be Riemann integrable. If that is not the case, let me know.

Comment: This is the case, it is bounded in $[\epsilon, 1]$ and continuous there and so integrable. It is also integrable in $(0,1)$ as the limit (I have stated earlier) exists.